# Error: html Container 'idchart' not found (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, charts

I created a pieChart with amCharts 4 but I got this message

> html container 'chartdiv' not found

This is a parent component

```html
<div class="col-12 mt-4">
   <app-gender-age-range-chart [chartId]="chartId"></app-gender-age-range-chart>
</div>
```

and here is the 'div tag' for my chart

```html
<div id="{{chartId}}"></div>
```

In the component.ts, i declared **@Input()**

```js
  @Input()
  chartId: string;

  chartRender() {
   // chart code
  }
```

`chartRender()` is placed in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting a viewChild of the element to ensure it is initialised, e.g:

Copied from JediManJS at https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1324

> Hello. I got the same issue and found more elegant, than setTimeout
> function, way. In the template, I added templateVariable to div:
>
> ```
> <div id="bar-lines-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px" #chartElement></div>
> ```
>
> In the component, I made next:
>
> ```
> @ViewChild('chartElement') chartElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
> ```
>
> and in am4core.create function:
>
> ```
> const chart = am4core.create(this.chartElement.nativeElement, am4charts.XYChart);
> ```
>
> Working well.

Comment: owhh, it work, but do you know why id='chartdiv' doesn't work?

Comment: Not too sure, it should work after ngAfterViewInit() like you had it according to documentation, I think it might just be a bug with am4core